# Which structured data to use on pages with multiple news?

Tags: seo, structured-data

I have a page which lists 15 news briefly, and if you click on one of them, you can read the whole article.
Right now I'm using CollectionPage (You can see that here: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fhearthstonehungary.hu%2Fnode).

I've been using this for awhile, but now I started to wonder, that this is maybe bad practice.

Is that okay here? Or should I use NewsArticle (I use that when you read the whole article), or something entirely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, creating 15 collection pages on a single page is a very bad practice.

A simple WebPage scheme is just enough.